# Conditional expectations related to Black-Scholes formula

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

While computing the price at time $t$ of a European call option with strike $K>0$ and maturity $T>0$ for $t$ in $[0,T]$, I encountered the following conditional expectation which I cannot compute ($\sigma, r>0$ are just constants):

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left.\max\left\{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(T-t)+\sigma(W_T-W_t)}-\frac{Ke^{-rT}}{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t+\sigma W_t}},0\right\}\right|\mathfrak{F}_t\right]$$

Here $\{W_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ is a Brownian motion which is adapted to the filtration $\mathfrak{F}$. The lecture notes I am studying suggest now to set $$Y:=\frac{Ke^{-rT}}{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t+\sigma W_t}},$$ which is an $\mathfrak{F}_t$-measurable random variable and to compute the expectation
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\max\left\{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(T-t)+\sigma(W_T-W_t)}-Y,0\right\}\right]$$
while treating $Y$ as a constant. The latter problem can be easily solved (albeit some lengthy computations occur). The notes say that this approach is valid since the random variable $W_T-W_t$ is independent of $\mathfrak{F}_t$. The latter fact is clear to me. The entire computation would also be clear to me if $Y$ really were a constant which is definitely not the case.

So, having in mind the properties of conditional expectations (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties)), I am wondering why this approach is valid. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Here is a general fact which is at the basis of the computations you present: Let $\mathcal G$ denote a sub-sigma-algebra, $X$ and $Y$ some random variables such that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, and $u$ some measurable function such that $u(X,Y)$ is integrable, then $$E(u(X,Y)\mid\mathcal G)=v(Y),$$ where the function $v$ is defined by $$v(y)=E(u(X,y)).$$ In your context, $Y$ is as in your question, $\mathcal G=\mathcal F_t$, $$X=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(T-t)+\sigma(W_T-W_t)}$$ and $$u(x,y)=\max\{x-y,0\}.$$

Comment: @Did thank you! Do you have a reference where I can look up the proof? Unfortunately, I did not succeed in proving this more general result.

Comment: The classical approach to prove this is to consider the class $\mathcal U$ of functions $u$ such that the result holds. First step: $\mathcal U$  contains every function $u$ of a given type. Second step: $\mathcal U$ is stable by dominated convergence. Conclusion: $\mathcal U$ contains every measurable $u$ such that $u(X,Y)$ is integrable.